# How is the creation of point defects in semiconductors affected by strain?

Tags: research-level, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

When the effect of the strain on solids is discussed, normally the explanation is the following: under increasing stress, first point defects are created, followed by dislocations, then plastic deformation starts, etc. I am trying to find papers (books) where the first step is discussed in detail.

Surprisingly, it is not that simple: there are lot of papers (including very recent ones) where using MD methods the energies of defect creation are calculated. However, very few discuss what happens when significant strain (comparable with one where destruction starts) is applied.

Could someone help me to find a good reference?

Ideally, this should be the point defect formation energy as a function of strain. My naive expectation is that e.g. for vacancies this should be the function with negative derivative, linear in the small region near zero (up to few percent strain) which reaches zero around the plastic limit.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find much on this topic in a technical library.

This classic text is a complete treatise on the concept of dislocations and their interactions with various other defects in crystalline materials.

> *Theory of Dislocations*, by John Price Hirth, Jens Lothe

If entirely new to the field see:

> *Elementary Dislocation Theory*, by Johannes Weertman, Julia R. Weertman .

Comment: I'll take a look, but the titles make me think that not much about **point** defects is discussed there.

Comment: The non-conservative motion of dislocations drives the formation/destruction of point defects at dislocation jogs.

Comment: I am interested in the regime when no dislocations appear in the system. And no, there are no dislocations in the system. At least, their number is negligible.